# Will SQL Agent in automatic start up starts after we stop the agent manually

Tags: sql-server, database-administration

I want to know if we stop a sql agent service manually which is in automatic start up mode will it start automatically without our intervention?

Answer (score 1):

No, it will not restart automatically if you have stopped it manually. Automatic start up mode implies that the service will start up automatically whenever the server is started/restarted.

Comment: In Approximately 2 hours after i stopped sql agent started automatically with the msg:: SQLAGENT starting under Windows NT control. So is this not normal behaviour?

Comment: might be other user or job that check regularly and started it

Comment: Is this a production server or a dev server? Generally on the production server, you'll have maintenance tasks running which will look at the the status of various services (powershell scripts etc.). If they see a service is stopped, they can notify the DBA's or restart them automatically.

Comment: It's a Test server.. I dont think anybody would be interested to check the staus of the services in the box. I'm from DBA team and I did this activity off hours so probably no one would have interfered. But i want to know the actual behaviour.